# How to replace v=getch()

Tags: cout, breadth-first-search

This program was originally a c. but since i'm currently taking up the c++, we are required to use cout instead of printf,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

cout << "Enter the value in adjancency matrix in from of 'y' or 'n'\n";
cout << "If there exits an edge between two vertices than 'y'     otherwise 'n'\n";
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
cout << b[i];
for(int i=0;i<n; i++)
{
    cout << "\n" << b[i];
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
           //printf("%c ",v=getch());   <-----THIS WAS THE PREVIOUS CODE
            v = getch(); <---------THIS DOESNT WORK
         ajMat[i][j]=v;
    }
    cout << "\n\n";
}
```

i've tried searching online on how to replace it, however when I tried changing it to " v = getch(); " the output isn't the same as it was. can anybody tell me what is the right form of it on iostream? thank you...

Comment: What is the desired output and the output you get with v=getch()?